# Custom JSON Encoder raises "Object not JSON serializable" error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding

I am trying to create a custom JSON Encoder for one of my classes.
I have created a [simplified version](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/olajolebob.rb) to try the method and it works, but when I apply the method in my project it keeps throwing the error:

```
    json.dump(obj=self.tree, fp=f, cls=BookmarkEncoder, ensure_ascii=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type HTMLBookmark is not JSON serializable
```

The object I am trying to convert is a modified version of the BeautifulSoup `Tag` class, the code for the class is as follows:

```py
class HTMLBookmark(Tag, Node):
    """TreeBuilder class, used to add additional functionality to the
    BeautifulSoup Tag class. The following functionality is added:

    - add id to each folder("h3")/url("a") being imported
    - add property access to the Tag class' attributes
      (date_added, icon, icon_uri, id, index, title, type and url)
      which are usually found in the 'self.attrs' dictionary.
    - add a setter for (id, index and title)
    - redirect the self.children from an iterator iter(self.contents)
    to a list (self.contents) directly"""

    counter = itertools.count(start=2)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.name in ("a", "h3"):
            if not self.attrs.get("id"):
                self.attrs["id"] = next(__class__.counter)

    @property
    def date_added(self):
        date_added = self.attrs.get("add_date")
        if not date_added:
            date_added = round(time.time() * 1000)
        return int(date_added)

    @property
    def icon(self):
        return self.attrs.get("icon")

    @property
    def icon_uri(self):
        return self.attrs.get("iconuri")

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.attrs.get("id")

    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id):
        self.attrs["id"] = new_id

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self.attrs.get("index")

    @index.setter
    def index(self, new_index):
        self.attrs["index"] = new_index

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.attrs.get("title")

    @title.setter
    def title(self, new_title):
        self.attrs["title"] = new_title

    @property
    def type(self):
        if self.name == "h3":
            return "folder"
        elif self.name == "a":
            return "url"

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self.attrs.get("href")

    @property
    def children(self):
        """To standardize the access of children amongst the different
        classes."""
        return self.contents
```

The HTMLBookmark class inherits from Node:

```py
class Node:
    def create_folder_as_json(self):
        folder = {
            "type": self.type,
            "id": self.id,
            "index": self.index,
            "parent_id": self.parent_id,
            "title": self.title,
            "date_added": self.date_added,
            "children": [],
        }
        return folder

    def create_url_as_json(self):
        url = {
            "type": self.type,
            "id": self.id,
            "index": self.index,
            "parent_id": self.parent_id,
            "title": self.title,
            "date_added": self.date_added,
            "url": self.url,
            "icon": self.icon,
            "iconuri": self.icon_uri,
            "tags": self.tags,
        }
        return url

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.title} - {self.type} - id: {self.id}"
```

This is my custom encoder

```py
class BookmarkEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def defaut(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, HTMLBookmark):
            if o.type == "folder":
                return o.create_folder_as_json()
            elif o.type == "url":
                return o.create_url_as_json()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

and finally this is the code that triggers the error:

```py
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="Utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(obj=self.tree, fp=f, cls=BookmarkEncoder, ensure_ascii=False)
```

where `self.tree` is an `HTMLBookmark` object created by importing an HTML file using BeautifulSoup.

Do let me know if any further information is needed, thanks :) .

**Edit:**

Here is a link to a working [code sample](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/mijusayego.rb) and [html input](https://pastebin.com/YzdwCbiu) as advised by @Ulrich Eckhardt in the comments.

Comment: This doesn't need more info but more precise info: Extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. This means code that I put into a file, run it and see your error, without any guessing or interpretation from my side.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , I have added them to the post as you have advised, thanks :) !

Comment: No, sorry. I'm glad you have your answer, but links to volatile external sites with code don't count, exactly because they could change any time. Put it inline and make sure it is minimal. Don't add "edit" sections either, make your question look like from a single cast.

Comment: Then what should I do? if you check the links, you will see that the amount of code needed to have a functional snippet is a lot, and I don't think it will be very practical/readable to put all of it in the post.

Comment: You're supposed to take the code and check every single line if it is required. In particular, lines after an error which are never executed can be thrown right out. Site rules require *you* to do that, because in many cases the reduced problem scope makes the solution obvious, thus weeding out trivial questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo: `def defaut(self, o):` should be `def default(self, o):`